# LINQ - looping through rows of 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a 2d string array like this:

```
string myarr[,] = new string[100,4];
```

And I want to get the number of rows, that contains a value `vpp` on the 2nd column.

ie, with normal loop I would be doing like this:

```
int s = 0;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
  if( myarr[i,1] == "vpp" )
  {
    s++;
  }
}
```

How could we do it using LINQ ?

I  believe, this will iterate through all the elements of the 2d array, instead of row-wise looping:

```
s = (from string myRow in myarr where myRow  == "vpp"                                       
          select myRow).Count();
```

Am on mobile device(travelling and reading) now since I don't have access to Visual Studio, so I have just typed the codes above.

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't honestly bother using LINQ. As much as it is a cool language, it gets very confusing the more complex the iteration is. See for this i would guess, you would have a sum with a count, so `myarr.ToList().Sum(x => x.Count(y => y == "vpp"));`

Comment: `string myarr[,]` is a multidimensional array, but with `myarr[i][1]` you are accessing it like a jagged array (array of arrays). You should use it like  `myarr[i, 1]`, but note that multidimensional arrays are "incompatible" with LINQ, while jagged arrays are compatible.

Comment: God knows why I said "cool language", more like a cool language feature!

Comment: @xanatos, sorry for that. I was on mobile device. So was typing the code and I just forgot to use `myarr[i, 1]` instead of that `myarr[i][1]`. Thanks for correcting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var count = Enumerable.Range(0, myarr.GetUpperBound(0)+1)
                      .Count(r => myarr[r,1] == "vpp");
```

Comment: @xanatos, myarr.Length would be `(myarr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)*(myarr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)`

Comment: I think it would be `myarr.GetLength(0) * marr.GetLength(1)`, but you are right that `Length` is useless.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it would be better if I use LINQ for this kind of things, or should use the normal loop. I mean, I would need a few more times to do like this in my code. Any performance issues it could have?

Comment: @VppMan, working with arrays in `for` loop is natural (other languages, which doesn't support something like Linq, just use `for`). also `for` gives much more options for processing of items (e.g. you can't set "VPP" instead of "vpp" in array using LINQ). but if you need only to iterate over array once and calculate something, then LINQ code can be shorter

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = Enumerable.Range(0, myarr.GetLength(0)).Count(index => myarr[index, 1] == "vpp");
```